# RecyclerView with RoomDatabase an ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-viewmodel

I'm showing my recycler view like this:

```
   parrafoLeyViewModel.allParrafosLey.observe(this, Observer {  

    recyclerview_lectura_ley.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapterListar = AdapterListarLey(this, it, this)
    recyclerview_lectura_ley.adapter = adapterListar

   })
```

So when I insert data into the RoomDatabase my recyclerview restarts and goes back to the start

```
    GlobalScope.launch {
                    db.parrafoLeyDao().updateComentarioLey(
                        ComentarioLey(
                            idParrfo,
                            spTipoComentario.selectedItem.toString(),
                            etInserteComentario.text.toString()
                        )
                    )
                }
```

What I want is that when I insert the data it remains in the same position. I am using ViewModel

Comment: Where are you updating the data for the recyclerview?

Comment: I am inserting data in the database, each item in the recyclerview allows me to insert a specific data for each of these items

Comment: for each recyclerview item I insert a comment in the db but when I insert it the recyclerview moves to the beginning

Comment: the comments are not visible in the recyclerview, they are only inserted in the bd and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly passing the data to `Recycler View`

Please make sure your **Data Source** is wrapped inside a `Live Data`
And then pass this live data to your Recycler View Adapter.

This way `Recycler View` will only re-draw the changed item and not the entire list. Because Recycler View works well with Live Data.

Any method of `Recycler View` which will cause the list to re-draw should be excluded.
for e.g. `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Instead call `submitList()`

And lastly please go through below documentation:

1. [Recycler View Sample](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/RecyclerViewKotlin)
2. [RecyclerView.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.State)